# AngularJs and ionic. ion-slide-box with ng-repeat

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a odd problem when im using `<ion-slide-box>`.
In the browser and on android it looks as it should.
But on IOS 9.2 it duplicate or breaks with the error duplicate index. I set track by like this:

`<ion-slide ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles track by vehicle.spot_id">`

this gives the duplicate index error

and like this

`<ion-slide ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles track by $index">`

this duplicates the entire vehicles object

has anyone had this issue and know how to fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end i with a `div` and `ion-slides` had the same issue.

my solution to this issue is to loop through the object and assign `key, value` to a new object

```
$scope.vehiclesHolder = returnData; 
$scope.vehicles = [];
angular.forEach($scope.vehiclesHolder, function(value, key) {
    $scope.vehicles[key] = value;
});
```